# UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> to UTF8 String

Tags: c, swift, unsafemutablepointer, bridging

I have a UnsafeMutablePointer pointing at a C string, I want to convert the bytes at this pointer to a Swift String, the data is a C string, so UTF8.

Is it possible to iterate byte by byte until NULL? Or some easier way?

Comment: We are talink Objective-C here, i take it. `let str = String.fromCString(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CChar is an alias for Int8, so you can use [CChar-based methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init) here.

```
let str = String(cString: pointer)
```